# SQL IN clause multiple columns and multiple value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This query is fine works.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 330110042 IN (iItem01,iItem02,iItem03,iItem04,iItem05,iItem_1,iItem_2,iItem_3,iItem_4,iItem_5,iItem_6,iItem_7,iItem_8,iItem_9,iItem_10,iItem_11,iItem_12,iItem_13,iItem_14,iItem_15,iItem_16,iItem_17,iItem_18,iItem_19,iItem_20,iItem_21,iItem_22,iItem_23,iItem_24,iItem_25,iItem_26,iItem_27,iItem_28,iItem_29,iItem_30)
```

But this query didnt work.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 330110042, 330110002, 330110002  IN (iItem01,iItem02,iItem03,iItem04,iItem05,iItem_1,iItem_2,iItem_3,iItem_4,iItem_5,iItem_6,iItem_7,iItem_8,iItem_9,iItem_10,iItem_11,iItem_12,iItem_13,iItem_14,iItem_15,iItem_16,iItem_17,iItem_18,iItem_19,iItem_20,iItem_21,iItem_22,iItem_23,iItem_24,iItem_25,iItem_26,iItem_27,iItem_28,iItem_29,iItem_30)
```

How i work in SQL Server?

Comment: sql-server is one word for you tag

Comment: is 330110042, 330110002, 330110002 a finite list or can grow?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
For SQL, an MCVE includes a few lines of `CREATE TABLE ...` and `INSERT INTO ...` to define a toy-database to play with.

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more? Are Item01 etc. columns in a table? What is your goal - are you trying to find which column contains a particular value e.g. 330110042? Where do these values come from (e.g. as asked above, are they a fixed list or generated dynamically)?

Comment: Use AND or OR..

Comment: What would you want it to mean? Would it be true if _any_ value is in the list, or only if _all_ of the values are? What part of the documentation for [`IN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql) was unclear?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell your exact goal here, but one possibility would be to turn the list of values into a table structure of its own.  A Common Table Expression might work:

```
;WITH Ids AS
(
    SELECT 330110042 AS Id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 330110002
)
SELECT t.*
FROM   [Table] t
INNER JOIN Ids i ON t.iItem01 = i.Id OR t.iItem02 = i.Id OR...
```

But, maybe a solution with [`UNPIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) would be more elegant.  I presume that your table has a primary key column called `Id`:

```
;WITH Unpivoted AS
(
    SELECT Id, ColName, ColValue
    FROM   (SELECT Id, iItem01, iItem02, iItem03
            FROM   [Table] t) p
    UNPIVOT
    (ColValue FOR ColName IN (iItem01, iItem02, iItem03)) AS unpvt
)
SELECT t.*
FROM   [Table] t
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Unpivoted u
               WHERE  t.Id = u.Id
               AND    u.ColValue IN (330110042, 330110002))
```

Of course, you would add all the necessary columns.  I added only the first three for this example.